# Are "wuzzy" and "was he" homophones?

Tags: poetry, rhymes, homophones

Can you have multiple-word homophones? If not, what would such pairs of same-sounding multiple words be called?

---

There is the funny/children's rhyming poem *Fuzzy Wuzzy*:

> *Fuzzy Wuzzy was a bear.
>
>   Fuzzy Wuzzy had no hair.
>
>   **Fuzzy Wuzzy** wasn't **fuzzy, was he**?*

The punchline of the joke in this poem is in the last line where the bolded sections are unexpectedly pronounced identically. (At least, I know American & British speakers who 'get' that joke).

Going on [this definition of homophone](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/homophone):

> a word pronounced the same as another but differing in meaning,
>   whether spelled the same way or not

the sounds made up of multiple words seem to fall outside of this meaning. Also "Wuzzy" seems to not be a "real" word (with a definition) or at least is only used in this context. Other definitions I've read seem essentially the same.

**So, are "wuzzy" and "was he" homophones? If not, what are they (if anything)?**

---

<sub>I wasn't able to find attribution for this poem but would add it if anyone knows it. Wikipedia at least [has little detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_Wuzzy).</sub>

Comment: For most British English speakers, "was" when stressed is pronounced with the vowel in the first syllable of "positive" rather than the vowel in the first syllable of "cousin".

Comment: @sumelic Interesting! My English wife normally does exactly as you say but when she recites the poem in the question she says it differently to form the expected rhyme. I guess that is a learned behavior.

Answer (score -3):

Not a true homophone, at least not in most English dialects.

Wuzzy = wɑzi;
Was-he = wɔzhi

It'd be most correct to call them a quasi-homophone.
As I understand it, homophones are still homophones if one of the choices has more than one word, so long as they sound alike.

Comment: I imagine that the OP has [ˈwʌzi] for both places in the rhyme, and that this is the source of their question.

Comment: In U.S. pronunciation, I think you'll find the vowels are the same and we lose the [h] when saying "was he" in casual speech. When I learned this ditty as a kid, I had no sense that this was a stretch.